# Visual Basic reading from file - one line and separating it

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, file-io, textbox

So I'm making application, where you have to log into.
So I got login screen and TextBoxes for both username and password.
I've got a file where all the information about logins is saved and it's formatted like this:

```
Username|Password
AdminUsername|AdminPassword
```

Username = the username
Password = the password
Information is stored in .lst file.
So I want to read the file and scroll through all the lines and compare if let's say:

```
If TextBoxUsername.Text = usernameString And TextBoxPassword.Text = passwordString Then
    'code here
End If
```

But I can't figured out how to read and separate texts, I only know how to read the WHOLE line but not separate the line into 2parts: 1st part as "usernameString" and 2nd part as "passwordString".

Comment: Are you using VB 6 or VB.NET?

Comment: The [TextFieldParser class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cakac7e6.aspx) was designed to make this very simple.  Just replace the , with a | in the example code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To split a string of text on a delimiter, use the [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx) method and specify the delimiter character as an argument. For example:

```
Dim items As String() = line.Split("|"c)
```

The first item in the array (`items(0)`) will be the user name because it was on the left-hand side of the `|` separator in the original string, and the second item in the array (`items(1)`) will be the password because it was on the right-hand side.

Of course, this approach still has a lot of problems… For one thing, storing passwords in a plain text file is a horrible idea. I hope this is only for learning purposes, and even then, it's never too early to start learning about security!

Comment: I've had this problem time ago and I solved with the same function written by Cody Gray